# i am facing django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError Cannot resolve bases, when i run python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django

I have two apps, coreapp and product app. As all models in product app have common fields , i created a BaseModel in coreapp and then inherited the BaseModel in the models in product app. Then i ran python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate. After that i made some changes in the models, I added `abstract = True` in BaseModel and renamed some fields in the models in product app. Then i ran python manage.py makemigrations. Now, when i run python manage.py migrate i get the following error

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'product.Attribute'>, <ModelState: 'product.Category'>, <ModelState: 'product.Product'>, <ModelState: 'product.AttributeValue'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
 in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more
```

Below are the two models

coreapp/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

product/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from project_root.coreapp.models import BaseModel
# Create your models here.

class Attribute(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class AttributeValue(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attribute_object = models.ForeignKey(Attribute,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attribute_values')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent= models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.FloatField()
    qty = models.BigIntegerField()
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detail= models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    category_object = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I ran python manage.py makemigrations first time i got the following migration files.

coreapp/migrations/0001_initial.py

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BaseModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

product/migrations/0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 4.1 on 2023-10-15 05:59

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('coreapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Attribute',
            fields=[
                ('basemodel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, 
                                                    on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
                                                    parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False,
                                                    to='coreapp.basemodel')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
            bases=('coreapp.basemodel',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('basemodel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, 
                                                    on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
                                                parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
                                                to='coreapp.basemodel')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('parent', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
                                            to='product.category')),
            ],
            bases=('coreapp.basemodel',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('basemodel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, 
                                                    on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
                                                    parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
                                                    to='coreapp.basemodel')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=500)),
                ('price', models.FloatField()),
                ('qty', models.BigIntegerField()),
                ('sku', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('detail', models.TextField(max_length=5000)),
                ('category_object', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
                                                    related_name='products', to='product.category')),
            ],
            bases=('coreapp.basemodel',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AttributeValue',
            fields=[
                ('basemodel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, 
                                                    on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
                                                    parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
                                                    to='coreapp.basemodel')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('attribute_object', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
                                                    related_name='attribute_values', to='product.attribute')),
            ],
            bases=('coreapp.basemodel',),
        ),
    ]
print('product migration 1')
```

then I added `abstract=True` in BaseModel and renamed fieild attribute_object to attribute  in AttributeValue model and category_object to category in Product model. After that i ran python manage.py makemigrations and got the following migrations files

coreapp/migrations/0002_delete_basemodel.py

```
# Generated by Django 4.1 on 2023-10-15 06:03

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('product', '0002_rename_attribute_object_attributevalue_attribute_and_more'),
        ('coreapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='BaseModel',
        ),
    ]
```

product/migrations/0002_rename_attribute_object_attributevalue_attribute_and_more.py

```
# Generated by Django 4.1 on 2023-10-15 06:03

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('product', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='attributevalue',
            old_name='attribute_object',
            new_name='attribute',
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='product',
            old_name='category_object',
            new_name='category',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='attribute',
            name='basemodel_ptr',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='attributevalue',
            name='basemodel_ptr',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='category',
            name='basemodel_ptr',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='product',
            name='basemodel_ptr',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='attribute',
            name='created_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='attribute',
            name='id',
            field=models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, default=1, primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
                                    verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='attribute',
            name='updated_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='attributevalue',
            name='created_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='attributevalue',
            name='id',
            field=models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, default=1, primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
                                    verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='attributevalue',
            name='updated_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='category',
            name='created_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='category',
            name='id',
            field=models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, default=1, primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
                                    verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='category',
            name='updated_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='created_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='id',
            field=models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, default=1, primary_key=True, serialize=False, 
                                    verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='updated_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
        ),
    ]

print('product migration 2')
```

Now when I run python manage.py migrate i get the error

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'product.Attribute'>, <ModelState: 'product.Category'>, <ModelState: 'product.Product'>, <ModelState: 'product.AttributeValue'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
 in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more
```

I tried migrating the app separately in different order like

```
python manage.py migrate product
python manage.py migrate coreapp
```

i also tried changing the order of dependencies in migration files

but none worked.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), you try to perform the first inheritance method ([Abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)). Setting `abstract = True` in your `BaseModel.Meta` is the way to go.
But creating multiple migrations for this change probably confuses Django.

Delete all your migrations (from `coreapp/migrations` AND `product/migrations`) and re-run `manage.py makemigrations`. The created initial migration should only create your 4 concrete models (Attribute, AttributeValue, Category, Product) under `product/migrations`. You should not have new migrations in `coreapp/migrations` app.

Comment: is there any way to solve this without deleteing the migration files because I have read that deleting migrations files is not a good practice?

Comment: Deleting a migration is a bad practice once you commited and pushed your migration files to your repository, and eventually applied them in production or/and on other developers working directory. While developping / creating new models, you can delete migrations and recreate them to ensure your migrations files works as expected and are bug-free BEFORE pushing your work to the repository.